# Use VS2017 to publish WebAPI , get stuck in `preparing profile`

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

Right click project -> publish -> select publish to folder -> publish

then got stucked in “preparing profile” .  (I'vs waited for 10 mins)

[image]

Comment: Try to open VS 2017 as run as administrator and give a try.

Comment: Try to log out and log in from your current logged in account on the top right hand side in VS IDE

Comment: still 'preparing' , running as administrator.

Comment: My colleagues get the same problem. So I think this is not relate to my computer.

Comment: Turns out that `.pubxml` was damaged. I use VS2015,  it shows me the real problem when I click publish. Strange that VS2017 just let me waiting....

Answer (score 80):

Go to your project folder ang go to "Properties\PublishProfile" and delete all profiles. Then try to publish again.

Comment: This worked for me! I took over a project that already had publishing profiles.This should be the answer.

Comment: This was spot on. I guess I could have removed files one at a time to see which was the offending file but this was the fastest solution and since my deployment is simple this made the most sense time wise.

Comment: To anyone looking where to find Properties\PublishProfile' located. Open the file explorer of the website , there is folder called 'Properties' , Then go to 'PublishProfiles'. Delete everything in this folder and try to publish again. It works for me now.

Comment: Removing all those profiles and restarting VS did it for me...thanks!

Comment: This worked for me... but it's shocking that this bug is still present 1 year later  in VS2017 v15.9.2  (particularly as there seems to be a new VS2017 update every 2 weeks...)   What is really scary is that the PublishSettings files (freshly exported from my Azure portal) no longer seem to work.

Answer (score 7):

**Are you using ftp publishing ?**

> Looks like an [issue](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/24972/publish-not-working-in-vs-2017-ide.html) with VS2017 and the status says still under
>   investigation.

From the thread:

*We are aware of the issue with ftp publishing. The bug has been fixed and should be available in an upcoming release.*

Please do following

- Delete all files in the Properties\PublishProfiles folder.
- Close Visual Studio.
- delete the user preference file .suo
- Create a new profile and try again.

If you are still running into issue,You can use publish profile from command line using [dotnet build command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/publishing/web-publishing-vs) or msbuild command

- `dotnet build /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=FolderProfile`
- `msbuild /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=FolderProfile`

Comment: No,  just publish it into local folder , not to FTP or IIS. And I tried delete publishprofiles and .suo, still can't publish

Comment: Turns out that `.pubxml` was damaged. I use VS2015,  it shows me the real problem when I click publish. Strange that VS2017 just let me waiting....

Comment: Delete all files in the Properties\PublishProfiles folder has been fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 3):

Delete the Folder named PublishProfiles fix the problem. I believe is there a issue related to read/write folder problems.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Team Explorer->Manage Connections and Connect to your project. Than creation of Publish profile is working